# Jacoco code coverage is affected by AspectJ

Tags: java, code-coverage, aspectj, jacoco

We're using AspectJ in our project and also Jacoco for test coverage report, currently we're facing an issue that due to AspectJ changed the byte code during compiling phase, which makes the code coverage report not correct. One example is due to AspectJ adds extra if-else statement, then the branch  coverage shows something like 1/4 but actually there's no condition branch in the source code.  Is there some good way to tell Jacoco to ignore all code generated by AspectJ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The same applies with lombok as well. But I don't think you can exclude methods generated by the AspectJ and/or lombok as in runtime, it's just all class files and code coverage is on the same. I would look for a solution as well.

Comment: I don't know AspectJ, but ideally you would test the class in isolation and test the cross-cutting logic separately.  If you're trying to test that the integration is working, you should already have 100% coverage.

Comment: @Karthik R, I don't know it can help or not but you can refer to this discussion https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jacoco/HziLWA3uT6g for more information of this issue.

Comment: Will check. Thank you :)

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm a Clover developer at Atlassian. 

The Atlassian Clover measures code coverage by instrumenting source code, not the byte code. As you're weaving your code using AspectJ, you shall get accurate code coverage results using Clover, as it's instrumentation phase will happen before AspectJ's instrumentation.

Comment: @Marek - Can you point me to instructions/documentation to setup openclover 4.2 code coverage for a project that uses aspectj and spring ? I am able to get the mvn clean clover:setup test clover:aggregate clover:clover going but am not sure how I must integrate the clover-aspectj-compiler. The coverage tree map does not work either. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am copying here the answer I just wrote on the JaCoCo mailing list:

You have two options with AspectJ if you want to avoid it compiling from source:

1. Use LTW with the weaving agent.
2. Move your aspects into a separate Maven module. Compile your Java modules with the normal Maven Compiler Plugin and the aspect module with AspectJ Maven. Then create another module which just uses AspectJ Maven in order to do binary weaving on a Java module, using both previously created artifacts as dependencies. In this scenario you need to make sure that JaCoCo offline instrumentation is bound to a phase before binary weaving is done.

The easiest way out, though, would be to test your aspects in isolation and also the Java code without aspects and measure coverage there without any issues.

Answer (score -1):

@RajeshTV:

Instructions how to use clover-aspectj-compiler are here:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/Clover+AspectJ+Compiler

These instructions are valid for OpenClover as well. Just download the:

- [org.openclover:clover-aspectj-compiler:1.0.0](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3Aorg.openclover%20a%3Aclover-aspectj-compiler)
- [org.openclover:clover:4.2.0](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3Aorg.openclover%20a%3Aclover)
- and aspectj-rt + aspectj-tools JARs

Next call them like this:

`java -cp "clover-4.2.0.jar:clover-aspectj-compiler-1.0.0.jar:aspectjrt.jar:aspectjtools.jar" com.atlassian.clover.instr.aspectj.CloverAjc -d <output directory> <list of files>`

It will produce *.class files in the specified directory as well as create clover.db database.

You have to call the command above from your Maven build, for instance by using the `exec:exec` goal.

Please note that the clover-aspectj-compiler does not have a dedicated Maven plugin to do this automatically, so it's your job to write the whole plumbing.